# How to analyze RL circuit with sequential switching?

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, inductor

I am trying to solve this question:

---

[image: problem]

---

However, I am having difficulties solving as I only have come across circuits which are initially closed then opened, not vice versa as is the case here. Specifically, I am trying to construct the simplified circuit for `t<0`. Usually, for the latter case, the inductor is a short circuit for the 20 Ohm resistor if t<0. However, I am unsure how it acts as this circuit starts open and then becomes closed.

So far, all I have been able to do is to a source transformation, making the current source a 150 V voltage source and combining the 10 and 5 Ohm resistors.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for t<0 you have this circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdGt7L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

first, you should calculate IL for t<0:
  [image]

When SW1 move from a to b we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI0ngH.png)</sup>

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXc9CS.png)</sup>

the equivalent resistor of 5 and 20 ohm is 4 So you have :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3dlk6.png)</sup>

[image]

to obtain voltage equation we derivate the current equation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! From my understanding, in the second last equation for V = L di/dt, you used I = 10e^-80.2*t. Where did this come from? I assumed it came from the line above, however I(t) = 10e^-0.2 * e^-80*0.01 doesn't equal such.

Comment: I just calculate C1 int that line, not i.

Comment: Where did you get the i in di/dt from then?

Comment: In the second circuit we have i=c1*e^(-80t) where c1 is 10e^(-0.2) . To obtain voltage we need to calculate Ldi/dt .

Comment: But I = c1*e^(-80t) = 10e^(-0.2) doesn't equal 10e^(-80.2t)

Comment: Sorry for my miscalculations, you are right, thanks my friend .

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, why is it V(15-10) @ t = 15 and not simply V(15)?

Comment: Because sw2 switch in t=10ms, so the last circuit begin at t=10 ms.   t=10 ms ,as t=0 ms for the last circuit.